# How to tell webpack not to compile CSS?

Tags: webpack

Can I make global exception not to apply loaders for CSS (or other file types).

Now I'm just getting an error:

```
...
ERROR in ./css/vendor/index.css
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude it, add `exclude` option to css loader

```
loaders: [
  //
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'css-loader?minimize',
    exclude: /index\.css/
  }
]
```